# unzip a file from another folder

Tags: shell, gzip

How can I unzip a file from another folder?

```
gunzip -d /home/tomcat_dev/HN/radd/input.txt.gz
```

unzips that file to the same folder. But if I want to bring it to my folder? When I do this:

```
gunzip -d /home/tomcat_dev/HN/radd/o.txt.gz /home/tomcat_dev/
```

it gives me a: `gunzip: /home/tomcat_dev/ is a directory -- ignored`

Comment: That's been already answered [here](http://superuser.com/a/139422).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is as simple as below:

`gunzip -c filepath.gz > anotherDirectoryPath`

More on [gunzip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gzip#gunzip_and_zcat), also refer to the [man page](http://linuxmanpages.com/man1/gzip.1.php).

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
gunzip -c -d /home/tomcat_dev/HN/radd/o.txt.gz > /home/tomcat_dev/o.txt
```

Comment: It works! 10x a lot

Answer (score 1):

Normally I'd use a combination of `mkdir` and:

```
gzcat /path/to/somefile.gz >/some/new/path/output
```